# jQuery: is 'DOMSubtreeModified' the best way to handle dynamically added elements (mobile device)?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bind

I'm using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to detect if the browser is on a mobile device. If true it needs to hide a facebook share button as it doesn't work properly on mobile devices and instead a facebook feed option is used.

As the elements are added dynamically I used the following:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
        $('#your-dialog-id').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
              $(this).find('.db-share').addClass('db-share-hide');
        });
}
```

`#your-dialog-id` is a jQuery UI modal.

**This works** but: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: well if you have control over the injection code then you alays do the addClass right after inject

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it, but why can't you just do `$('.db-share').hide();` on pageload ?

Comment: @Huangism I tried that but unfortunately the PHP code to test for mobile is more unwieldly. I tested a PHP solution to addClass when mobile but it didn't catch all browsers.

@adeneo I load a lot of dynamic elements that's decided by the user's actions and unfortunately I couldn't use .hide() as I only want to hide them on a mobile platform. As this is all inside a facebook frame it was getting very complicated. That's what led me to  `DOMSubtreeModified`. I just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: the iPhone one did not like `DOMSubtreeModified`. In the end I went with a back in solution http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone one did not like DOMSubtreeModified. In the end I went with a back end solution code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect